# Which one of the following is correct?

Tags: present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, progressive-aspect, present-continuous

Which one of the following is correct?

> (1) I am **cooking** lunch.
>
> (2) I **have been cooking** lunch.

Besides, if aforementioned are correct, I want to know the difference between ***I am cooking*** and ***I have been cooking***. My key concern is about *cooking lunch*.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, with slightly different meanings:

> I **am cooking** lunch.

Only means you are now or will be doing this

> 1) What are you doing now?  I **am cooking** lunch.
>   2) Who's cooking lunch today? I **am cooking** lunch.

#2 is an acceptable and informal way of expressing you will be making lunch.

> Who's cooking lunch today? I **will be** *cooking lunch*

may be better.

> I **have been cooking** lunch

implies you have already started cooking lunch and may or may not continue to be cooking lunch now.

> What have you been doing?  I **have been cooking** lunch for an hour.

Your question has made me hungry...

Comment: +1.  And: Who has been cooking lunch all week?  I have been cooking lunch all week.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are correct grammatically, but there's a difference in meaning between them.

I am cooking lunch.

You usually use the present continuous for something that is happening at this moment/at the time of speaking.

Hey, Dan. What are you doing? I am cooking lunch.

You can also use it for an action happening nowadays.

What are you doing in the restaurant (nowadays). I am cooking lunch.

In addition, you can use the present continuous for a future action, for example:

Who is cooking lunch tomorrow? I am doing/cooking it.

As for the present perfect continuous, you usually use it to refer to an action happening over a period of time leading up to the present.

What have you been doing for 2 hours? I have been cooking lunch.

You can also it for an action which ends just before the present.

The present perfect can also be used to talk about an action repeated up to the present.

I have been cooking lunch in this restaurant since I joined it.
.

Answer (score 1):

These are two common first-person tenses in English. **I am cooking lunch** is present continuous. However, it can have different meanings based on the sentence predicate. Consider:

> I am cooking lunch right now.

vs.

> I am cooking lunch later today.

Your second sentence is present-perfect tense. It's meaning is singular:

> I have been cooking lunch for hours.

or some such frame of time.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Present continuous** is used for an action happening right now. (Not in the **past**.)

   > » *I'**m cooking** lunch.*
2. **Present perfect continuous** is used for an event that began in the **past** and is **still** in progress in the present.

   > » *I **have been cooking** lunch.*

The action is not yet completed in both tenses, but the main difference here is that the former gives you information about something happening right now (event in the present) and the latter tells you about something that started in the **past** and is **still** in progress.

3. In addition, the present continuous can be also used for **future arrangements**:

   > » *I'm **cooking** lunch at two o'clock tomorrow afternoon.*
4. Note also that present continuous can also be used for something that is happening **temporarily**, not necessarily at the moment  of speaking:

   > » *I'm **cooking** lunch in the afternoons.*